# QThread Executing Multiple Times

Tags: python, pyqt4, signals-slots, qthread

I have written a short program here designed to record and play back my mouse motions. I've implemented a simple GUI in `PyQt` and had it working in the past. Recently I decided to update the code to make it less 'hacky' by implementing `QThread` instead of using `processEvents()` in a main loop.

The code below executes, but behaves strangely. When running the code, here is what happens:

> **Input 1:** I press Record
>
> **Console Output:** `isRecording = True`
>
> **Input 2:** I press Stop
>
> **Console Output:** `Stopped!`
>
> **Input 3:** I press Play
>
> **Console Output:** `isRecording = True`
>
> **Input 4:** I press Stop
>
> **Console Output:**
> `Stopped!`
> `Play!`
> `Playback complete!`

I am unclear why after pressing `play` the program attempts to record again, and only after pressing stop does it begin playback. Furthermore, after this stretch of weirdness, it continues to exhibit this similar type of output with minor deviations.

My guess is it has something to do with reassigning the thread signal `started` depending on whether or not I am calling the `play` or `record` member function of the `CursorCapture` class.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

### Code

```
import win32api
import sys
import time

from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4.QtCore import Qt, QPoint
from PyQt4 import QtCore

class MouseRecord(QtCore.QObject):
    
    finished = QtCore.pyqtSignal()    
    
    def __init__(self):
        
        super(MouseRecord, self).__init__()        
        
        self.isRecording = False
        self.cursorPath = []
    
    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()  
    def record(self):
    
        self.isRecording = True
        self.cursorPath = []
        print "isRecording = " + str(self.isRecording)

        while(self.isRecording):
        
            #print "Recording"            

            self.cursorPath.append(win32api.GetCursorPos())
            time.sleep(.02)            
            
        self.finished.emit()
        print "Stopped!"
    
    def stop(self):
    
        self.isRecording = False
    
    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()    
    def play(self):
        
        print "Play!"

        for pos in self.cursorPath:
            #print "Playing"            
            win32api.SetCursorPos(pos)
            time.sleep(.02)        
            
        print "Playback complete!"
        self.finished.emit()            
        

class CursorCapture(QtGui.QWidget):
    
    def __init__(self):
        
        super(CursorCapture, self).__init__()
        
        self.isRecording = False
        self.mouseRecorder = MouseRecord()
        
        self.myThread = QtCore.QThread()
                
        self.mouseRecorder.moveToThread(self.myThread)
        self.mouseRecorder.finished.connect(self.myThread.quit) 
                        
        self.initUI()
        
    def initUI(self):
        
        self.recordBtn = QtGui.QPushButton("&Record")
        self.stopBtn   = QtGui.QPushButton("&Stop")
        self.playBtn   = QtGui.QPushButton("&Play")        
        
        self.recordBtn.clicked.connect(self.record)
        self.stopBtn.clicked.connect(self.stop)
        self.playBtn.clicked.connect(self.play)
        
        self.hBox = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        
        self.hBox.addWidget(self.recordBtn)
        self.hBox.addWidget(self.stopBtn)
        self.hBox.addWidget(self.playBtn)
        
        self.setLayout(self.hBox)
        
        self.setWindowTitle("Cursor Capture")
        self.show()
        
    def record(self):
        
        self.myThread.started.connect(self.mouseRecorder.record)
        self.myThread.start()        
        
    def stop(self):
        
        self.mouseRecorder.stop()
        
    def play(self):
        
        self.myThread.started.connect(self.mouseRecorder.play)
        self.myThread.start()

def main():

    qApp = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    
    cursorCapture = CursorCapture()
    
    sys.exit(qApp.exec_())    
            
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After more investigating and playing around I discovered the problem. When reconnecting signals to slots, you have to make sure to `disconnect()` the previous signals. What was happening was:

Press record. Record signal is connected.
Press play. Since record signal wasn't *disconnected*, it fires first. THEN, the play signal gets connected and executed. This type of behavior stacks, and this is why things were acting so strangely.